# Error: This operation is not allowed when there are no records displayed. Please execute a query that returns

Tags: siebel

I have added the following code in the WebApplet_Load of Service Request Applet.It's giving me the above error once, I tries to open the SR screen from the application.

```
try
   {
      var currBC = this.BusComp();
      with (currBC)
      {
        ActivateField("Restrict_drop_down");
        ClearToQuery();
        //BC.SetViewMode(3);;
        TheApplication.SetProfilAttr("SR Type", GetFieldValue("Restrict_drop_down"));
        ExecuteQuery(ForwardBackward);
      }
   }
   catch (e)
   {
      TheApplication().RaiseErrorText(e.errText);
   }
```

Any idea on how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do GetFieldValue when the BC is in Query mode. You have just done ClearToQuery, so you have to execute the query first, check for FirstRecord(); and then do a GetFieldValue();

Also, during the WebApplet load the first BC query is not finished running. It might not be the best place to write this code.

Please check with a siebel expert on your team, such kind of code needs to be placed carefully.